# User should not be able to delete given symbol in textfield which is a text

Tags: swift, character, textfield, restrict

[image]

func textField(textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
return true
}

I have to restrict user to delete this symbol from textfield in swift. User can delete any thing from textfield without deleting this symbol.

Comment: why not move it out of the text field? if not, what did you try - show the code - and what went wrong?

Comment: I can't move this symbol out of the textfield and i have not done any thing for this.except this if (string.characters.count == 1){
            if currencyDetail != ""{
                amount.text = currencyDetail
            }
            return false
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the most probable scenario is that the Euro symbol will always be in the textfield and will be the first character, I would check if the range of characters to change is longer than 0 and starts at 0.  (This will work regardless of the symbol in the first position)

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if range.length>0  && range.location == 0 {
            return false
    }
    return true
}
```

If however, the euro symbol is not always in the text field, you could check whether the user is deleting this symbol or not by getting a reference to the string the user is changing and checking whether this contains a euro symbol:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if range.length>0  && range.location == 0 {
        let changedText = NSString(string: textField.text!).substringWithRange(range)
        if changedText.containsString("€") {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Craig your solution works for me. and i like the way you have explained it in both way.